# What does "power group" mean?

Tags: meaning

> "Recent events in the Ukraine and our dependency on the Russians for transportation to the space station [make it] even more important to reignite our space program."
>   So argued Gene Grush, former head of the propulsion and **power group** at NASA's Johnson Space Center, in a series of articles published by Fox News earlier this year. But why is it so "important" that the U.S. "reignite" its space program? What sparked this sense of urgency, and what are America's space exploration companies doing to fix it?

What does that mean?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Propulsion and power** is the generic name or description of the group. It is not capitalized so its probably not the organizational name.

I am not technically knowledgeable in this field, but I suppose **power** here refers to electrical or other power systems in the spacecraft.

Incidentally, the usage of "reignite" and "sparked" in the paragraph is kind of a play on the theme.

Answer (score 5):

It is not "power group" you have here but "the propulsion and power group" -  the group of scientists and engineers at NASA who are concerned with designing and maintaining the systems which provide inflight power to propel and operate US spacecraft.